# Hibernate configure how to create an object

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, orm

**Is it possible to configure Hiberate/NHibernate not to use the default constructor to create objects when reading from the database?**

When Hibernate reads 10 customers from a table, it creates 10 `Customer` objects. It does this by

```
Customer c = new Customer();
```

Can I tell Hibernate to do the following instead:

```
Customer c = ACertainStaticFactory.CreateNewCustomer();
```

or even to manage a factory instance:

```
ACertainFactory factory = .....;
Customer c = factory.CreateNewCustomer();
```

or even more sophisticated, to pass a parameter which I set before:

```
// My client code
Query query = session.CreateQuery(...);
// either:
query.SetSomeParameter(someObject);
// or:
session.SetSomeParameter(someObject);

query.List();

// Hibernate should then behave like this:
Customer c = new Customer(someObject);
// or
Customer c = ACertainStaticFactory.CreateNewCustomer(someObject);
// etc.
```

**Is that possible in anyway? If yes: How? If no: Is there an alternative?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When Hibernate reads 10 customers from a table, it creates 10 Customer objects. It does this by (...)

More precisely, Hibernate uses [`Class<T>#newInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) to create new instances of an entity, which relies on the no-arg constructor. Hence the need to provide it.

> Is that possible in anyway? If yes: How? If no: Is there an alternative?

Your requirement looks close to the [Possible to have Hibernate hydrate objects with Factory?](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=931496&view=previous) thread on Hibernate's forums so I'll quote Steve's answer (updated to match current names):

> This is totally doable. In fact you
>   have two options:
>
> 1. create a custom [`EntityPersister`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/persister/entity/EntityPersister.html) implementation;
> 2. create a custom [`Interceptor`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html) implementation, specifically the
>      [`Interceptor.instantiate()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#instantiate%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.EntityMode,%20java.io.Serializable%29) method will
>      be of interest to you...

I think I'd go the interceptor way (not sure about your complex scenario but implementing the factory approach looks pretty easy).

Comment: Hi Pascal. I implemented my own `Interceptor`, and it did it. I inherited `EmptyInterceptor` and overrode the `OnLoad` instead of `instantiate`, because so far I only need to set one property on the object, and this way NHibernate takes the work of creating the object from a class string and setting it's ID from a ISerializable object. With this I achieved something similar like my last line of code, `Customer c = new Customer(someObject)`, instead just setting a readonly property `c.TheObject = someObject`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, may be helpful:

http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2008/11/entities-behavior-injection.html

Comment: The result sounds good, still looks quite complicated compared to implement an interceptor. (Yet have to read both resources in depth yet.)